# Is there a way to create a dynamic form that generates questions based on rows in an Excel table?

Tags: excel, forms, sharepoint, excel-online, microsoft-forms

I have an Excel table that has data added to it periodically. I have a second table that describes the connection between the items in the first table. For the sake of an example:

First table with data:

[image]

and 
second table with connections.

[image]

I would like to create a form that allows you to pick multiple item pairs from table 1, write a "connection" for each pair, and then submit that into table 2. Since table 1 has new data added periodically, the form would have to be somehow linked to table 1 to always allow a connection to be made with all the items.

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but none of the forms I found that could be integrated with Excel had this "dynamic" functionality. Is there a workaround or a way to achieve this.

(In reality, the tables and names are more complex, and everything is hosted on Sharepoint online.)